# name undefined but inspector shows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create dynamic list in react.js

```
uList = () =>{
    return this.state.user.map((u)=>{ 
        console.log(u);
        return <li onClick={this.setC} id={u} name={u}>{u}</li>; 
    });  
}
```

Now setC is defined like this :

```
setC = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.name);
}
```

It console.log *undefined* always, but inspect shows li has names.

Here is my full code : https://jsfiddle.net/denial__rr/j3ub7msh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is an attribute, you need to use the `getAttribute()` function to get it.

```
setC = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('name'));
}
```

Fixed fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aj2updfr/

Note that when rendering a list of items, each item should have a key. You can read more about this in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). You should probably do somethink like this (assuming that there are no repeats):

```
uList = () =>{
    return this.state.user.map((u)=>{ 
        console.log(u);
        return <li key={u} onClick={this.setC} id={u} name={u}>{u}</li>; 
    });      
}
```